# Failing to install azureml-sdk due to ruamel.yaml

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to install azureml-sdk but I keep getting an error related to the ruamel.yaml package. Specifically, I receive the following error message when the package attempts to build wheels for ruamel.yaml:

`Building wheels for collected packages: ruamel.yaml Building wheel for ruamel.yaml (setup.py) ... error error: subprocess-exited-with-error`

Please see the whole error message here: https://pastebin.com/raw/9UxqDqDN

I tried upgrading pip. I tried reinstalling wheels. I tried installing ruamel.yaml seperately after which I received a message that the requirements were already met. I ensured that I have Microsoft Visual C++ distribution installed.

I also created a new Anaconda environment and tried to install azureml-sdk there. This also did not work; I received the same error message.

Comment: Are you running this inside an Azure ML studio notebook?

Comment: Can you try to upgrade the package and try again pip install --upgrade ruamel.yaml

Comment: Can you update your setup.py in the question so I can test it in my environment? As, I tried running a sample setup.py with azureml-sdk, ruamel.yaml and wheel and it got installed locally in vs code successfully. It  also ran successfully in Azure ML studio

Comment: @SiddheshDesai I am trying to install it locally so I can code on VSC and deploy easily to my Studio Notebook. I did the upgrade and I already had the most recent version (Requirement already satisfied: ruamel.yaml in c:\python311\lib\site-packages (0.17.21)). 

What is this setup.py you're talking about? I only tried installing using pip, no code yet. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/ml/install?view=azure-ml-py)

Comment: I tried to install azure  ml sdk with pip install and also other packages, It got installed successfully, According to your error code × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully. I thought you're using setup.py to install packages.

Comment: Can you create a python file in vs code with name setup.py and enter this code :- from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='azure_ml_sdk_with_dependencies',
    version='0.1',
    description='Install Azure ML SDK with dependencies',
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=[
        'azureml-sdk',
        'ruamel.yaml',
        'wheel'
    ]
) After entering this code open your terminal in vs code and enter python setup.py install command to install this packages from setup.py If you want I can add the process in answer? both pip, setup.py and studio?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is getting encountered with the installation of Azure Machine Learning SDK for Python on the latest pip (>20.1.1) in the conda base environment for all released versions of Azure Machine Learning SDK for Python. Refer to the following workarounds:

Avoid installing Python SDK on the conda base environment, rather create your conda environment and install SDK on that newly created user environment. The latest pip should work on that new conda environment.

For creating images in docker, where you cannot switch away from conda base environment, please pin pip<=20.1.1 in the docker file.

conda install -c r -y conda python=3.8 pip=20.1.1

Comment: I already did that and it didn't help ("I also created a new Anaconda environment and tried to install azureml-sdk there. This also did not work; I received the same error message.")